# Generating function of $2^ {n \choose 2}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Is there an exponential generating function for the sequence $a_n = 2^  {n \choose 2}$? The context is that I want to find the number of simple graphs on n labeled vertices where each connected component has at most 5 vertices. The latter structure I'm okay with but I can't get the generating function for  number of simple graphs on n labeled vertices.
I have tried a couple of different solutions. First off I defined the generating function as

$A(x) = \sum_{n \geq 0} a_n x^n /n!$

Then letting $b_n = ln(a_n)$ and defining a generic exponential function for B(x).

$B(x) =\sum_{n \geq 0} b_n x^n /n! = \frac{ln(2)}{2} x^2\sum_{n \geq 0} \frac{x^{n-2}} {(n-2)!} = \frac{ln(2)}{2} x^2 e^x $

Then I thought I could write

$A(x) = e^{B(x)} = 2 e^{x^2 e^x/2}$

However this is giving the incorrect sequence.

The other attempt I made was similar but using the power series expansion and getting

$B(x)=  ln(2) \frac{x^2}{ (1-x)^3}$

and

$A(x) = 2e^{\frac{x^2}{ (1-x)^3}}$

This is also incorrect.

Comment: The main issue here is that writing $\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^nf(x,n)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty(2^{(n-1)/2}x)^nf(x,n)$ still leaves a function of $n$ in the exponent.

Comment: There's none unless you consider *formal* power series ($\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n/n!$ diverges if $x\neq 0$).

Comment: What do you mean by considering the formal power series? I thought that was what I was doing.

Comment: @holmesie7: See OEIS *[A006125](https://oeis.org/A006125)*.